# Restoring Qt app after minimized to dock, using dock shortcut on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, shortcut, dock

Single-clicking an application icon in the Dock launches that application or, if the application is already open, switches you to that application and brings forward all open windows in that application.

In my Qt app, I do not see this behavior. I have a dock shortcut, I minimize the app on dock, and if I click the minimized instance the app is restored.

If I click the application icon in the Dock (dock shortcut), nothing happens.

(I can right-click, and "Show All Windows" - but that is not similar to the behavior of all other apps)

I tried to place the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15363738/1217150

Placing `qDebug` statements,

```
if(test) qDebug("registered");
```

in the constructor, and

```
void MyApplictionClass::onClickOnDock()
{
  qDebug("dock clicked"); 
}
```

On start-up I get both messages... but after minimizing, or any time after start-up, there is no reaction to dock shortcut being clicked or double clicked.

Full code insertion:

MyApplicationClass.h:

```
#include <objc/objc.h>    
#include <objc/message.h>
class MyApplicationClass: public QApplication
{
    ....
    bool dockClickHandler(id self, SEL _cmd, ...);
    void onClickOnDock();
};
```

MyApplicationClass.cpp:

```
MyApplicationClass::MyApplicationClass()
{
....
    objc_object* cls = objc_getClass("NSApplication");
    SEL sharedApplication = sel_registerName("sharedApplication");
    objc_object* appInst = objc_msgSend(cls, sharedApplication);
    if(appInst != NULL)
    {
        objc_object* delegate = objc_msgSend(appInst, sel_registerName("delegate"));
        objc_object* delClass = objc_msgSend(delegate, sel_registerName("class"));
        const char* tst = class_getName(delClass->isa);
        bool test = class_addMethod((objc_class*)delClass,
                                    sel_registerName("applicationShouldHandleReopen::hasVisibleWindows:"),
                                    (IMP)dockClickHandler(appInst, sharedApplication), "B@:");
        if(!test) qDebug("not registered");
        else qDebug("registered");
    }
.....
}

bool MyApplicationClass::dockClickHandler(id self, SEL _cmd, ...)
{
    Q_UNUSED(self)
    Q_UNUSED(_cmd)
    onClickOnDock();
    return true;
}

void MyApplicationClass::onClickOnDock()
{
    qDebug("dock clicked");
}
```

Perhaps I did something wrong ? There are a few items I don't understand... The referred post had `dockClickHandler` not part of the class... I just don't know where they have it... And I had to give it arguments when I registered it, otherwise it refused to build. Still, it seems to do... something... just not the right thing. In that code, I do not see where the app will react to clicking the dock.

Is this the correct approach ? Or how can I get my app to restore when its dock shortcut is clicked ?

(OSX 10.6-10.9, Qt 4.8)

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to this: [QT on OS X, how to detect clicking the app Dock Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143369/qt-on-os-x-how-to-detect-clicking-the-app-dock-icon), the onClickOnDock should not be a member of the class.

You CAN put it as a normal function inside the MyApplicationClass.cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack at least for Qt 5.9.1, when you can implement onClickOnDock() without platform specific code at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488514/8695355