# Can't re-open a Qt app if I reimplement QCloseEvent

Tags: macos, qt

I'm trying to let the app hide to dock when user click on the close button.

So I implemented QCloseEvent:

```
void xxx::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *e) 
{
    hide ();
    e->ignore ();
}
```

Now if I click on close button, it works but I can never bring it back

Nothing happens when I click on the dock

I guess I'm missing an event? What should I do now?

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143369/qt-on-os-x-how-to-detect-clicking-the-app-dock-icon